# Flutter: Show Sticky bottom container on mobile app

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm new to flutter and I wanted to create a offline indicator on my app, just like the other common app. If the user is offline I wanted to show sticky bottom container saying "you are offline". Is there any package or method for me to show it on all of my screen without manually writing the offline text 1 by 1 on each of the screen ? Thanks before

Comment: i think this doc can solve your problem just change the position of the box https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/1/flutter-automatically-show-internet-connection-message-on-offline-or-online/

Answer (score 0):

Use the connectivity plus package to check connection status and you can use snackbar to display the message

[Connectivity plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)